# Does the ability from Sorcerer's Wand deal combat damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

If I were to equip [Virtus the Veiled](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bVirtus%20the%20Veiled%5d) with [Sorcerer's Wand](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSorcerer%27s%5d%2b%5bWand%5d) and used the Sorcerers Wand's ability, would that be considered combat damage allowing Virtus's ability to trigger?

Comment: If it's done as an ability, it's not combat damage, combat damage is dealt by an attacking or blocking creature as part of combat.

Answer (score 5):

### Sorcerer's Wand does not allow the triggering of Virtus the Veil's ability

From the Comprehensive Rules Glossary:

> Combat Damage
>   Damage dealt during the combat damage step by attacking creatures and blocking creatures as a consequence of combat. See rule 510, “Combat Damage Step.”

Damage from spells or abilities such as the ability granted by Sorcerer's Wand is not combat damage because it is not a consequence of combat.

Answer (score 3):

Combat damage is damage that is dealt as a result of combat. Any other damage from spells or abilities is not combat damage. The ability that Sorcerer's Wand grants deals damage directly, so it is not combat damage and will not trigger Virtus the Veiled's triggered ability.

Answer (score 3):

Sorcer's Wand does not deal combat damage, so no. Combat damage is a very specific type of damage that's dealt by creatures in the Combat Damage step. Virtus only triggers on combat damage, which isn't happening here.